# File permissions for mapped folders on host machine

Tags: docker

Im running the official WordPress container for development, and have it mapped to a local folder on my host machine (OS X). Everything runs fine except WordPress can't write any files as it has no permissions as far as I can tell.

I've even tried adding 777 permissions to the uploads folder, it then creates the first folder but it goes to try adding another it fails again.

Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: I recall this being a problem with VirtualBox (that is, you get on the Docker VM and don't have write permissions), but I can't remember how I solved it.